# windows memory managment: check if a page is in memory

Tags: windows, memory-management

Is there a way, in Windows, to check if a page in in memory or in disk(swap space)? 
The reason I want know this is to avoid causing page fault if the page is in disk, by not accessing that page.

Comment: Why? *(Why would you not let the OS do its job of managing memory? What is so special about what you do, is it so close to hardware level?)*

Comment: I'm curious what the actual application is where it's an option **not** to access swapped data when a request has been made for it. What is your solution for?

Comment: That's not possible.

Such a status indication could never be reliable.  It can tell you that a page is swapped out but it *never* guarantee that a page is still in RAM when you actually access it.  A check-and-pagelock scheme is unreasonably expensive and not provided.

Comment: @HansPassant: The OP seems to be asking for a hint for performance reasons, so I would guess an imperfect heuristic would serve. Still, circumventing the system in this way does seem like a very dubious thing to do.

Comment: An operating system provides a few very basic guarantees.  Being able to use memory efficiently is certainly a core one.  You only ever look for a workaround if your program *doesn't* use memory efficiently.  Trying to write code to ensure that the operating system does a better job with memory than your program does is putting the cart in front of the horse.

Answer (score 2):

There is no documented way that I am aware of for accomplishing this in user mode.

That said, it is possible to determine this in kernel mode, but this would involve inspecting the Page Table Entries, which belong to the Memory Manager - not something that you really wouldn't want to do in any sort of production code.

What is the real problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I am working on an memory malware scanner. In this case, by knowing if the page the location of a page(memory ot disk) i can take different actions.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of Virtual Memory is to abstract this sort of thing away. If you are storing your own data and in user-land, put it in a data-structure that supports caching and don't think about pages.

If you are writing code in kernel-space, I know in linux you need to convert a memory address from a user-land to a kernal-space one, then there are API calls in the VMM to get at the page_table_entry, and subsequently the page struct from the address. Once that is done, you use logical operators to check for flags, one of which is "swapped". If you are trying to make something fast though, traversing and messing with memory at the page level might not be the most efficient (or safest) thing to do.

More information is needed in order to provide a more complete answer.

Comment: My code is in kernel-space. I am writing on an memory malware scanner. In this case, by knowing if the page the location of a page(memory or disk) i can take different actions.

Comment: I wrote somethign similar for linux+Xen VM's for detecting malware packing. M$ probably has internal documentation for things like this, but it is most likely privileged information. 

You probably need to a) figure out how to get ahold of these docs, b) find someone who "just knows" these things through experience, or c) fire up a tool to discover in-memory objects or reverse engineer the kernel. In my case, I just had to read the Linux source to figure this stuff out. Now sure how to go about it for Win kernel. That's about as much as I can help you with on the closed-source side of things.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to see if any one in the community knows about some undocumented kernel data structure that hold the info i need. Other wise, i will revert to option c or a.